# Toggle plus and minus icon using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

I have a sidebar which consist of list containing sub-menu.A plus icon when the menu not expanded.A minus icon when the menu is expanded. there should be a toggling between the icon accordingly.

My project fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanacchu/a9mL374h/11/)

I'm not able to get minus when sub-menu get expanded.please help out.

```css
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.main ul.collapsed:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.main:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f068";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you css to:

```
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.main.collapsed:before  {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.main:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f068";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.collapsed.sub-main:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f067";
  display: inline-block; 
 margin-left:28px;
}
.sub-main:before {
   content: "\f068";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block; 
 margin-left:28px;
}
```

add a class collapsed to the closed elements

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6wcfjuvt/)

Comment: Thanks for the the help.It worked perfectly..Thank you again.

Comment: don't forget to click the green check :)

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways to achieve this

1. Using bootstrap + CSS + jquery

   In this case you have to remove and add i.e. toggle the class of the image with the 
   help
   of bootstrap's navbar class. (I have toggled font-awesome class)

> HTML

```
 <nav  class="navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top d-block d-lg-none">
  <div id="nav-mobile" class=" d-flex flex-row nav-flex-row">
    <div class="p-3 mr-auto"><img class="img img-fluid" src="img/png/logo.png" /> 
    </div>
   <div class="p-3">
    <span class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria- 
        expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="false" style="color:white"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-mobile-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
  <div id="top-menu"  class="navbar-container collapsebar-main">
    <div style="flex:1" class="">
        <a class="active js-scroll-trigger " href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
    <div style="flex:1">
        <a class=" js-scroll-trigger" href="#product">Products</a>
    </div>
    <div style="flex:1">
        <a class=" js-scroll-trigger" href="#partners">Partners</a>
    </div>
    <div style="flex:1" class="testimonial-nav">
        <a class=" js-scroll-trigger" href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
 // Toggles between close and show icon (Navbar) 
 $(function(){
  $('#navbarResponsive')
  .on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".fa-bars")
      .removeClass("fa-bars")
      .addClass("fa-times");

   })
  .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
     $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".fa-times")
      .removeClass("fa-times")
      .addClass("fa-bars");
   });

});
```

2. Using Jquery

   In this case you just find the image tag and toggle it using jquery's toggle function

> HTML

```
<div id="infoToggler">
  <img src="image 1 url" width="60px" height="60px"/>
  <img src="image 2 url" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```